# How to Completely Uninstall Xcode and Clear All Settings

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, uninstallation

I have an issue that I can only assume is with Xcode, where my apps take forever to run and crash the phone/restart about 75% of the time. I tried using older versions of the code that I'd saved instead, but they had the same effect, which they didn't use to have about a month ago.

I've looked up every single possible way to solve this issue for the past few weeks have haven't found anything, so I want to completely uninstall Xcode and clear all settings; but I can't find a way to do this. I can uninstall it, but when I reinstall it, it still has all of my old settings and lists of projects etc. How can I completely uninstall it?

Comment: I did end up solving it, and it didn't have to do with Xcode specifically, but required the device I was using be cleared.

Comment: Found that if you have an emoji in the pathname of where Xcode is stored, the Xcode simulators after iOS 11 don't run correctly. I put my Xcode into a folder with a bunch of related aliases. The folder was named "" so it's path was /Applications/Development//Xcode.app. This caused only the new simulators to hang. The old ones ran fine as before.

Answer (score 239):

For complete removal old Xcode 7 you should remove

1. `/Applications/Xcode.app`
2. `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist`
3. `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist`
4. `~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode`
5. `~/Library/Application Support/Xcode`
6. `~/Library/Developer/Xcode`
7. `~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator`

Comment: In xcode8 timeframe, change #3 and #4 to end with `com.apple.dt.*` since Instruments and other xcode components are also writing plists

Comment: and `~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator`, can be cleaned as: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33419301/coresimulator-folder-very-big-ok-to-delete-content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33419301/coresimulator-folder-very-big-ok-to-delete-content)

Comment: Something **Important**: you can delete anything under `/Library/Developer/` directory, such as `CommandLineTools` and `CoreSimulator`, EXCEPT `PrivateFrameworks` subfolder; or else your newly installed Xcode will crash until you put it back. Just be careful about the system directory.

Comment: @DawnSong I had accidentially deleted the files under `\Library \Developer` , I then installed commandline tools for macOS. Still my xcode keeps on crashing. My Developer folder currently has `commandlines Tools` in the directory. How should I fix this problem?

Comment: @AakashDave Copy from your friend's mac, haha.

Comment: @kpod13 I followed your advice, but libraries are showing red in .xcworkspace now and I get some errors. Could you please have a look at my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50237202

Comment: if you deleted `PrivateFrameworks` - https://stackoverflow.com/a/50176504/3446071

Comment: Following the manual steps in this guide: https://macpaw.com/how-to/uninstall-xcode-on-macos I deleted the whole `~/Library/Developer/` folder and this solved my problem, making it possible to download and install Xcode from the App Store. (This was for Xcode 9 & 10.)

Comment: I had to delete this too **rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/XCTestDevices**

Answer (score 78):

For a *complete* removal of *Xcode 10* delete the following:

1. `/Applications/Xcode.app`
2. `~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode`
3. `~/Library/Developer`
4. `~/Library/MobileDevice`
5. `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist`
6. `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist`
7. `/System/Library/Receipts/com.apple.pkg.XcodeExtensionSupport.bom`
8. `/System/Library/Receipts/com.apple.pkg.XcodeExtensionSupport.plist`
9. `/System/Library/Receipts/com.apple.pkg.XcodeSystemResources.bom`
10. `/System/Library/Receipts/com.apple.pkg.XcodeSystemResources.plist`
11. `/private/var/db/receipts/com.apple.pkg.Xcode.bom`

But instead of 11, open up `/private/var/`in the Finder and search for "Xcode" to see all the 'dna' left behind... and selectively clean that out too. I would post the pathnames but they will include randomized folder names which will not be the same from my Mac to yours.

**but if you don't want to lose all of your customizations**, consider saving these files or folders before deleting anything:

1. `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/CodeSnippets`
2. `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/FontAndColorThemes`
3. `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/KeyBindings`
4. `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates`
5. `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist`
6. `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles`

Comment: shoot I also deleted the downloaded `.xip` file

Comment: AppStore doesn't work after that...

Answer (score 45):

1. Open `Storage Management`

   - Go to  > About This Mac > Window > Storage Management
   - Or, hit <kbd>⌘ + Space</kbd> to open *Spotlight* and  search for `Storage Management`.
2. Select `Applications` on left pane.
3. Right click on `Xcode` on the right pane and select delete.

This will remove XCode from the installed applications list of your Mac's App Store.

**Update**: This worked for me on macOS Sierra `10.12.1`.

Comment: Might need to add some info around what versions of OS X this is valid for, don't see it as of 10.11.6

Comment: I don't remember whether it moved Xcode.app to Trash. But the above process removed XCode from AppStore.

Comment: "This will remove XCode from AppStore." Really?

Comment: @AlexanderVolkov From App Store *on your Mac*. My installation somehow got corrupted, and I was unable to uninstall or re-install the software. Even installation from the DMG file kept failing, because it is marked as installed in App Store.

Comment: On `10.13.3` the delete option is there but it does not do anything

Comment: This will not delete all meta files like here https://stackoverflow.com/a/33812614/1179925

Answer (score 23):

Before taking such drastic measures, quit Xcode and follow all the instructions here for cleaning out the caches:

[How to Empty Caches and Clean All Targets Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714372/how-to-empty-caches-and-clean-all-targets-xcode-4/6247073#6247073)

If that doesn't help, and you decide you really need a clean installation of Xcode, then, in addition to all of the stuff in that answer, trash the Xcode app itself, plus trash your `~/Library/Developer` folder and your `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist` file. I think that should just about do it.

Answer (score 11):

**FOR UNINSTALLING AND THEN BEING ABLE TO REINSTALL XCODE 9 CORRECTLY**

I followed the topmost answer for deleting Xcode 7 and found a major error, deleting `~/Library/Developer` will delete an important folder called `PrivateFrameworks`, which will actually crash Xcode everytime you reinstall and force you to have to get your friends to send you the PrivateFrameworks folder again, a complete waste of time seeing if you needed to uninstall and reinstall Xcode urgently for immediate work purposes.

I have tried editing the topmost answer but see no changes so below is the modified steps you should take for Xcode 9:

**Delete**

`/Applications/Xcode.app`

`~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.*` (Generally anything with com.apple.dt. as prefix is removable in the Preferences folder)

`~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode`

`~/Library/Application Support/Xcode`

Everything in 
`/Library/Developer` directory except for 
`/Library/Developer/PrivateFrameworks`

Comment: I think you mean remove `/Library/Developer` except for `/Library/Developer/PrivateFrameworks`, PrivateFrameworks doesn't appear to exist for me in the home folder version of `Library/Developer`

also note, that `/Users/USERNAME/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives` contains the xcode archives (as in archives of what you have built) so you might want to save that

Comment: Yeah for some PrivateFrameworks is there and if delete will cause crash if you need to reinstall Xcode afterwards, guess my instructions can be misread but I meant delete everything except for PrivateFrameworks

Comment: mgrandi is correct `/Library/Developer` is different than `~/Library/Developer`. The former contains `PrivateFrameworks` folder not the latter.

Answer (score 6):

This answer should be more of a comment against Dawn Song's comment earlier, but since I don't have enough reputation, I'm going to write it as an answer.

According to the forum page

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/11313

"In general, you should never just delete the CoreSimulator/Devices directory yourself.  If you really absolutely must, you need to make sure that the service is not runnign while you do that.  eg:"

```
# Quit Xcode.app, Simulator.app, etc
sudo killall -9 com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService
rm -rf ~/Library/*/CoreSimulator
```

I definitely ran into this issue after deleting and reinstalling Xcode.

You might encounter a problem trying to connect the build to a simulator device.  The thread also answers what to do in that case,

```
gem install snapshot
fastlane snapshot reset_simulators
```

Answer (score -12):

Run this to find all instances of Xcode in your filesystem:

for i in `find / -name Xcode -print`; do echo $i; done

Comment: This may show unexpected things if there are any file name clashed e.g like I have several folders called `Xcode Projects` and this would print them out.