# Xcode 7 - Code coverage data generation failed

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios9

When I run my tests I get an error:

> Code coverage data generation failed.
>   Unable to retrieve the profile data files from 'UIDevice'.

[image]

On console was printed warning:

> Timed out waiting 120 seconds for simulator to boot, current state is 1.

What is the reason?

Comment: Found a solution. Always restart your mac:-) restarting Xcode sometimes is not enough.

Comment: For me, restarting my iPhone helped.

Comment: When I encountered this issue, deleting the Derived Data folder and rebuilding fixed it.

Comment: In my case it was device screen locked. After unlocking device it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 15):

If you are integrating your project with a 3rd party dynamic framework, you may need to add a path in your build settings.  Look for ->Build Settings->"Runpath search paths" and make sure it includes the path to the framework.

I was just seeing this exact issue myself after setting up my a project to use a framework my team has been working on.  After updating this specific setting, the problem went away.  In my case, the path was identical to one I already had to set for the "Framework search paths" setting.

Answer (score 12):

I solved this problem, just like I solve most of those XCode Problems:

1. delete your projects files in your `DerivedData` (`Xcode>Preferences>Locations>DerivedData→` to jump there in finder)
2. `Product>Clean`
3. (keep alt-Button pressed) `Product>Clean Build Folder`
4. Quit XCode
5. Restart XCode
6. Remove your app from your device / simulator

Try again. 
In case it still doesn't work, use another simulator / device for a few runs. Sooner or later it will work again on the original one again.

Comment: Valid answer, fixes most of problems

Comment: I couldn't run unit tests using my device, but they ran when using a simulator. I encountered the same error as the OP. This answer solved that for me.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using cocoa pods, check this thread on the Cocoapods repository:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/5385#issuecomment-226269847

This fixed my problem:

Copying @dfleming response:

> For some reason, it appears that CocoaPods is not adding the "[CP]
>   Embed Pods Frameworks" build phase to the UI Tests target when
>   generating the project workspace.
>
> I manually added this in and the UI Tests were runnable again.
>
> This build phase should run the following script: (Replace
>   {YourProject} with your project name)
>
> `"${SRCROOT}/Pods/Target Support
>   Files/Pods-{YourProject}UITests/Pods-{YourProject}UITests-frameworks.sh"`

Comment: This works but your adding a custom script. You could add the framework to the target. It's a bit long winded but in the end you don't have a custom script.... Go to your UI Test target > Build Phases > Link Binaries With Libraries. This has a list of frameworks linked to your UI Test target. Click the "+" and then the Add Other button in the prompt. Now navigate to Pods/Target Supporting Files/ Your UI Test Target and select the ".sh" file.

Answer (score 5):

I experienced exactly the same error and eventually got it working, these are the steps I took.

1. Tried restarting Xcode and the simulator, after cleaning and deleting the app, that never worked.
2. Then I restarted the Mac as suggested, but that still didn't work.
3. Then I chose a new device to test against in the simulator, was previously using 5s and switched to 6, and that worked.

Interestingly, when I switched to the iPhone 6 simulator, it showed the Apple logo with a loading bar, before running the app and working.

When switching back to the 5s simulator it did exactly the same, with the Apple loading bar, which it hadn't done before, and then the 5s worked.

So it looks to be a simulator issue, and switching to a different device worked. Resetting the content and settings may be the solution for a non-working device.

Comment: Mine continues to fail on device, but with simulator indeed works

Comment: Omg, i was searching this problem again and i see a comment of mine. This time i'm testing a mac app, so i have nothing to change the device with. if i disable the coverage it compiles but is not executing the tests.

Answer (score 3):

Cocoapods `link_with` method can cause this issue!

I was getting the exact same error on xcode 7.2 - no number of simulator or device resets seemed to clear it up.  After completely rebuilding my UITest targets though things worked fine.  After spending a lot of time in a massive git diff of the `.pbxproj` file I found a solution for my project.  Im not sure if it addresses the root cause for everyone who is seeing this error but it definitely clears things up for me.

From the project info below "deployment target", "Configurations" will list all the possible configurations for your application.  Expand the configuration you are trying to run and you should see a list of all your targets.  In my case cocoapods had automatically added a base configuration for the UITest target:

[image]

Set this to `none` in the dropdown.
Next in the menu to the left select your UITest target then `build phases`  You will need to remove `check pods manifest.lock` `link binary with libraries` `emebd pods frameworks` and `copy pods resources`.

Finally go to your pod file and check for any mentions of your UITest target or targets.  In my case I had been specifying at the top of my podfile:

```
platform :ios, '8.4'
use_frameworks!

link_with 'My App', 'My UITesting Target' 

pod 'A Pod', '~> 1.0'
```

Instead the podfile should list specific dependencies for each target:

```
platform :ios, '8.4'
use_frameworks!

target 'My App', :exclusive => true do
    pod 'A Pod I want to use in my app', '~> 1.0'
end
```

Assuming you weren't using any pods in your UITests the target should build again without errors and tests will run!

My understanding of root of this problem is that each UITest target builds two separate bundles, one for the app and one for the UITest controller.  Unfortunately cocoapods `link_with` logic modifies all the specified targets to expect the pods.framework in their bundle.  The build phase scripts add the framework to the app bundle but not the UITest controller bundle, so then when you launch your tests that UITest controller bundle appears to be missing frameworks and xcode aborts the installation.

If you were using pods in your UITests you should be able to specify these in the same way:

```
target 'My UITesting Target', :exclusive => true do
    pod 'Another Pod I want only for UITesting', '~> 1.0'
end
```

And when you run `pod install` everything should link up correctly.

Comment: Seems to be interesting to verify this. I will let you know if it works for me also

Answer (score 3):

This problem can also appears when you use Cocoapods with a framework where some dependencies are missing.
For example if you are using *Framework A*, and this framework depends of *Framework B* but in the Podspec of *Framework A* the dependency is not declared.

Comment: I had the same problem!

Answer (score 2):

One of the reasons this can happen is if the host application that the test target is testing is not linked to the right dependencies. For example, if you have are testing a framework, make sure the host app is linked to those frameworks and also embedded. [image]

Answer (score 2):

My problem was caused by incorrect deployment version of unittest target. Tested App deployment version was 7.0, but the unittest's was not set up correctly automatically. It was set to 10.0, while my simulator's version was 8.4. Change the UT target's deployment version to 8.0 in build settings and then all the problems disappeared.

Comment: Please note that my app use cocoapod heavily, but I didn't do anything with it for unittest. Comment for answers arround about cocoapod.

Answer (score 2):

I tried a bunch of these solutions with no luck.  I turned off the Code Coverage option in my Scheme's Test section, which suppressed the error but Tests would not run.  Then I noticed quite a bit of stuff in NSLog console.  Somewhere in there, it mentioned reference to a framework that I was no longer using and trying to load.

I searched the app for it, and Build Settings -> Other Linker Flags was trying to load the framework that wasn't there anymore.

I removed:
-framework 3rd_party_libname

Then tests worked again.  This was confusing, but please check for NSLog msgs.  I was using XCode 8.3

Comment: Brilliant, thank you!  This fixed it for me after all the restarting and cleaning didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

One or more of your simulators has gotten stuck. The only thing that always works to fix this for me is to reset the simulator content and settings from the Simulator menu.

[image: Reset Content and Settings...]

Note: this will delete all app data from the simulator.

Answer (score 1):

After a long time trying to figure this out, it turned out that I had to create a brand new test target.
Then after rebooting the device the problem no longer resurfaced.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had added Swift files to a framework that was (until then) purely Objective-C. The test bundle *did not* have any Swift code in it.

Once I added a Swift file to the test bundle, Xcode automatically updated some project settings and the error went away.

You should keep the Swift file in the test bundle, even though it may not contain any code. Either Xcode or Cocoapods evidently use the existence of Swift files in the test bundle to determine whether to run the tests in "swift mode".

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is probably the simulator failure.  Issues with the simulator are common, especially on first launch.

If the problem occurs even after successful simulator launch and connect, please post the details of the error.

To get the simulator to launch, I often have to cancel the first run (after launching Xcode cleanly), and try re-running a few times.

If this is repeatable, happens on multiple projects, and persists after relaunch and cleaning of the projects, consider submitting a defect to Apple if the Stack Overflow community cannot help.

Comment: You are right, this is the simulator issue. I do not know how to workaround this. Any ideas? I have tried to run the app on simulator, and... the same problem. It cannot connect.

Comment: My suggestion about retrying was all I could think of, since it what works for me (and my slow Mac).

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem but it was due to having a test target and renaming the application's target. Make sure you have a valid Host Application set.

- Choose the test target on the project page
- Under the General tab there should be a Host Application select box
- Choose the target you want to test against

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same issue :

Tried following things for different projects :

1.For project where i had some third party frameworks, The problem was that test bundle can't find the framework at runtime. For this update test target's Runpath Search Paths build settings by adding `$(PROJECT_DIR)/Frameworks` (assuming you keep your frameworks at that location)., It fixed my problem for this project
You can look for it at below location :

```
Project file -> Test target -> Build Settings -> Runpath Search Paths
```

2. In other workspace, When I changed my testing device to some other simulator or change the device itself. it helped.
3. Restart the xcode or your mac system.

hope it will help u

Answer (score 0):

**Carthage users:**

This happened to me after I added a new framework to my Cartfile.

I ran `carthage update` but forgot to drag the `.framework` file from Finder into the Embedded Binaries section of my app target!

Once I did that, the problem went away.

(Note this is a specific case of the general problem mentioned by @Mustafa above.)

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem on Xcode 8.3 on Sierra 10.12.4

I opened the Keychain Access application on my Mac

After a few seconds, I got several system pop-ups asking for my password, to grant permissions to Keychain items.

I entered my password into the pop-ups, and then my tests starting working.

Answer (score 0):

Steps that worked in my case
Delete the scheme and clicking Manage Scheme->Auto generate scheme resolved the issue in my case.

Issue was caused by installing the certificate in the simulator and in the keychain

Answer (score 0):

Using Xcode 9.1 with multiple build targets and standard compiler we were working on UI tests and I started seeing this problem.  So, you will probably hate me for this answer, and I fully expect it to be downvoted, BUT this actually worked for me: I had to completely remove Xcode and my project from my machine to make this error disappear.

I tried every single suggestion in this thread, some multiple times, tried clearing cache files, deleting derived data, tinkering with build settings, updating podfiles, cleaning, rebuilding after each attempt, cleaning the simulator, manually recreating the simulators in 'manage devices'. After hours and hours of frustration it was still a complete mystery why this machine was failing to build our UI test.  It seemed to work fine on other machines and on our CI.  In addition to the items in this thread I manually modified the pbxproj file to set all options related to code coverage to "NO".

Finally, I was 1 step away from reformatting the entire machine.  I decided to completely remove Xcode following the suggestions here: [Stackoverflow: How to completely uninstall Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31011062/how-to-completely-uninstall-xcode-and-clear-all-settings).

Specifically, I trashed our workspace, quit all programs, deleted all of the files listed, cleared content and settings from the simulator, deleted the simulator, turned the machine off for 20 minutes, came back, reinstalled Xcode, cloned the repository, and voila! No error.

Hope that solves the issue for someone.  It's the 'nuclear' option, and you should never ever have to do this, but like I said, this is the only thing that worked for me.