# Code Coverage Data Generation Failed

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

When i try to run my tests i get this error:
[image]

I tried as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32223965/xcode-7-code-coverage-data-generation-failed) erasing derived data, erasing contents of simulator, clean, clean build folder, restarting xcode but i still getting the same error. Notice i switched to version 1.0 of cocoapods and the issue can be related.