# Error : Code Coverage Data Generation Failed

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, unit-testing, cocoapods

> Error : 'Unable to retrieve the profile data files from `iPhone 6s Plus`.

I have added a dynamic library using `cocoapods` with pod version `1.0.1` with `Xcode 8.0` . I am getting this error when I try to run Unit Test cases.

After looking at some answers, I tried adding below `scipt` in Build Phase.

```
 "${SRCROOT}/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-{MyProjectName}Tests/Pods-{MyProjectName}-frameworks.sh"
```

But doesn't seem to work.

Comment: [this may help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38038052/xcode-code-coverage-data-generation-failed)