# Error when trying to run application after previously i deleted derived data Xcode 7.2

Tags: ios, xcode, runtime-error

Hey I keep getting this error. I think its because earlier i deleted everything in derived data folder and now i get this error when i try to run my project this is a new little test project I'm doing for the apple watch does anybody know how to fix it? Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recognize this issue and I tried to restart Xcode, my computer, clear cache, clean etc when I also had this problem, without any luck. The only thing that got it working for me was to **completely** uninstall Xcode and remove all files.  Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31011062/how-to-completely-uninstall-xcode-and-clear-all-settings) of how to do that.

Comment: Yea i just had to literally move all the file from this project to a completely new project

Comment: Did it solve it for you? I can recommend you not to clear that folder anymore :) @Hunter