# Completely uninstall Xcode and all settings

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode7, uninstallation, osx-yosemite

I am trying to completely uninstall Xcode. However I followed the post [How to Completely Uninstall Xcode and Clear All Settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31011062/how-to-completely-uninstall-xcode-and-clear-all-settings)

After following the instructions, I ran find for xcode string in my entire system and found the following locations.

Can I remove the below or should not I?

```
/private/var/db/receipts/com.apple.pkg.Xcode.bom
/private/var/db/receipts/com.apple.pkg.Xcode.plist
/private/var/db/xcode_select_link
/private/var/folders/rj/90swtn490tq7hgw36cmsln0m0000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/7.2-7C68/Xcode
/private/var/folders/rj/90swtn490tq7hgw36cmsln0m0000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/7.2-7C68/Xcode/CachedSpecifications-Xcode
/private/var/folders/rj/90swtn490tq7hgw36cmsln0m0000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/7.2-7C68/Xcode/CachedSpecifications-xcodebuild
/private/var/folders/rj/90swtn490tq7hgw36cmsln0m0000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/7.2-7C68/Xcode/PlugInCache-xcodebuild-Debug.xcplugincache
/private/var/folders/rj/90swtn490tq7hgw36cmsln0m0000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/7.2.1-7C1002/Xcode
/private/var/folders/rj/90swtn490tq7hgw36cmsln0m0000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/7.2.1-7C1002/Xcode/CachedSpecifications-Xcode
/private/var/folders/rj/90swtn490tq7hgw36cmsln0m0000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/7.2.1-7C1002/Xcode/CachedSpecifications-xcodebuild
/private/var/folders/rj/90swtn490tq7hgw36cmsln0m0000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/7.2.1-7C1002/Xcode/PlugInCache-xcodebuild-Debug.xcplugincache
/private/var/folders/rj/90swtn490tq7hgw36cmsln0m0000gn/C/com.apple.dt.Xcode.InstallCheckCache_14F1021_7C1002
/private/var/folders/rj/90swtn490tq7hgw36cmsln0m0000gn/C/com.apple.Xcode.501
/private/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/7.2-7C68/Xcode
/private/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/7.2-7C68/Xcode/CachedSpecifications-xcodebuild
/private/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/7.2-7C68/Xcode/PlugInCache-xcodebuild-Debug.xcplugincache
/private/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/7.2.1-7C1002/Xcode
/private/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/7.2.1-7C1002/Xcode/CachedSpecifications-xcodebuild
/private/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/7.2.1-7C1002/Xcode/PlugInCache-xcodebuild-Debug.xcplugincache
/private/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_ngzzzzzvzzzzzy/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/7.2.1-7C1002/Xcode
/private/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_ngzzzzzvzzzzzy/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/7.2.1-7C1002/Xcode/CachedSpecifications-xcodebuild
/private/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_ngzzzzzvzzzzzy/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/7.2.1-7C1002/Xcode/PlugInCache-xcodebuild-Debug.xcplugincache
/private/var/root/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.xcodebuild.plist
/private/var/root/Library/Preferences/xcodebuild.plist
/System/Library/Automator/Build Xcode Project.action
/System/Library/Automator/Build Xcode Project.action/Contents/MacOS/Build Xcode Project
/Users/mac1234/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode.Playground
/Users/mac1234/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.LSSharedFileList.plist
/Users/mac1234/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.Playground.plist
/Users/mac1234/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.xcodebuild.plist
/usr/bin/xcode-select
/usr/bin/xcodebuild
/usr/share/man/man1/xcode-select.1
```

Answer (score -1):

refer this link and do something like this using terminal n your mac,

http://recomhub.com/blog/how-to-uninstall-xcode-on-mac-os-x/

```
sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all
```

Its working and easy to do.

Comment: I already uninstalled xcode app. The list I mentioned is finding for xcode after removal.I have installed command line developer tools separately.

Comment: So now you can remove all the files of xcode you listed above. because now no need of xcode or simulator.

Comment: But I read that `/private/var/folders/rj/` are sensitive folders and should not be altered. So was just cautious and this is the mail reason for this question

Comment: Do not tamper with /var in any way.  If you want to get some space back then reboot.  The system will clear out what it deems needs clearing out.  That includes your swap space which may build up over time if you don't reboot and have insufficient ram.

Comment: Also you cannot delete some files in that folder bcs they are accessible only by root.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125666/discussion-between-kar-and-rams).