# The last time you opened Xcode, it unexpectedly quit while reopening windows

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, crash

When opening XCode 8.1, I get the popup message: "The last time you opened Xcode, it unexpectedly quit while reopening windows. Do you want to try to reopen its windows again?" (Screenshot attached above). On clicking either responses to popup, XCode crashes automatically.

When opening from the MACOS folder (Terminal) - Here are the logs:

```
"2016-11-02 11:04:05.300 Xcode[864:36864] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID DA4FDFD8-C509-4D8B-8B55-84A7B66AE701 for plug-in at path '~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/RealmPlugin.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs
2016-11-02 11:04:05.301 Xcode[864:36864] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID DA4FDFD8-C509-4D8B-8B55-84A7B66AE701 for plug-in at path '~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/InjectionPlugin.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs
2016-11-02 11:04:05.301 Xcode[864:36864] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID DA4FDFD8-C509-4D8B-8B55-84A7B66AE701 for plug-in at path '~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/GitDiff.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs
2016-11-02 11:04:05.302 Xcode[864:36864] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID DA4FDFD8-C509-4D8B-8B55-84A7B66AE701 for plug-in at path '~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/Alcatraz.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs
2016-11-02 11:04:10.823 Xcode[864:36953]  DVTAssertions: ASSERTION FAILURE in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DVTiOSFrameworks/DVTiOSFrameworks-11515/IDEiOSSupportCore/DVTiPhoneSimulator.m:615
Details:  Unexpectedly found two active proxied devices for companion dvtdevice-iphonesimulator:C111C1B1-CF09-4F3E-85EF-A553E76EB85B: dvtdevice-iphonesimulator:4A77CC36-BD55-4BFF-A82A-30CB2B670AA8 and dvtdevice-iphonesimulator:4A77CC36-BD55-4BFF-A82A-30CB2B670AA8
Object:   <DVTiPhoneSimulator: 0x7faa8209c730>
Method:   -_updateProxiedDeviceSet
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7faa82e22180>{number = 8, name = (null)}
Hints:   None
2016-11-02 11:04:10.955 Xcode[864:36953]  DVTAssertions: 
Backtrace:
  0   -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] (in IDEKit)
  1   _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2   _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  3   __45-[DVTiPhoneSimulator _updateProxiedDeviceSet]_block_invoke_2 (in IDEiOSSupportCore)
  4   __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke (in DVTFoundation)
  5   _dispatch_call_block_and_release (in libdispatch.dylib)
  6   _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib)
  7   _dispatch_queue_serial_drain (in libdispatch.dylib)
  8   _dispatch_queue_invoke (in libdispatch.dylib)
  9   _dispatch_queue_override_invoke (in libdispatch.dylib)
 10   _dispatch_root_queue_drain (in libdispatch.dylib)
 11   _dispatch_worker_thread3 (in libdispatch.dylib)
 12   _pthread_wqthread (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)
 13   start_wqthread (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)
Abort trap: 6
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
"
```

### How this started

I downloaded XCode 8.1 and installed it from the app store - over the XCode 8.0 I was using. After installing, I went to the devices tab and there were no simulators to work with?! Because of that, I went and added an iPhone 7 and iPhone 7+ simulator.

I then plugged in my phone, and started building/compiling it on my phone. I stepped away from my computer for a few seconds, came back and XCode had crashed while building.

Trying to reopen XCode, it has been giving me this popup/error/crash since.

I downloaded macOS Sierra 10.12.1, thinking maybe that would fix it. No luck.

I followed [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31011062/how-to-completely-uninstall-xcode-and-clear-all-settings), thinking that a clean install of XCode on my system would fix it. Also no luck.

I am now stuck on what to do. Steps to reproduce:

1. Download XCode 8.0 (GM)
2. Download and Install XCode 8.1 from Mac App Store
3. There Should be no simulators on the device tab, add a 7 and 7+ simulator.
4. Run your project on a device

Expected Results:

.XCWorkspace project to run like normal on my device (not simulator).

Also, for all the simulators to be in my "devices" list. (Why were these removed when updating?)

Actual Results:

Crashes out of XCode. Popup shows everytime even after clean install.

If you choose "Reopen" It crashes automatically. If you choose "Don't Reopen" It shows the startup menu for about a quarter second, then crashes.

Version:
Xcode Version 8.1 - macOS Sierra Version 10.12.1 (16B2555)

I believe (as terminal shows when running) that it has something to do with the device simulators I added. I am not sure how to delete those, though.

Also, I do not have a "Developer" folder under /Library/ for some reason. Unsure if that has to do with anything.

Comment: Sounds like a computer/software issue, not a programming language question . I would try apple.stackexchange.com  instead of this forum.  Regards.

Comment: It looks like you have some unsupported plug-ins in there: Realm, Injection, GitDiff, and Alcatraz. I'd get rid of those first.