# Dual Xcode setup broken. Builds crash on older iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos, ios7

I have a project that must support iOS 7, so I had Xcode 7.3.1 and the latest Xcode 8 installed.

Things were mostly fine. But now, all of the sudden, when I build my project and run it on iOS7, the app crashes during startup.

My colleague never had Xcode 8 installed. When they build the same source (with git repository) on the same device, everything works perfectly fine.

The app fails when it tries to access the `view` property of a view controller. That looks like this.

```
MyViewController *myViewCon = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:NSStringFromClass([MyViewController class]) bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

// Access the view property
UIView *view = [myViewCon view]; // CRASH HERE
```

Here's the error I get:

> Assertion failed: (tokenCount < maxCountIncludingZeroTerminator - 1),
>   function CUIRenditionKeySetValueForAttribute, file
>   /SourceCache/CoreUI/CoreUI-232.4/CoreTheme/ThemeStorage/CUIThemeRendition.m,
>   line 136.

**What I've tried**

Deleting both versions of Xcode and removing all files listed here: [How to Completely Uninstall Xcode and Clear All Settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31011062/how-to-completely-uninstall-xcode-and-clear-all-settings)

Then reinstalling only version 7.3.1.

Plus a full clean of the build folder.

I don't know what else to do.

Comment: Open the .xib, in the File Inspector, "Opens in", select XCode 7.x

Answer (score 0):

What could cause that is that your xib are set to be opened only from XCode 8, and this added some info/structure in the XML that are not the same as before, and could explain the crash.

To fix that:

1. Open your `.xib` file with XCode 8
2. Select `File Inspector`: [image]
3. Select `Opens In`:
   [image]
4. Allows it to opens with XCode 7.x:
   [image]

Comment: I thought of this. My coworker is able to build and run the same source from git using Xcode 7.1.3. So this can't be it. Just to be sure, I checked, and it's set to open in Xcode 7.

Comment: That's new info. Could you confirm that you have the same version of OSX?

Comment: I wrote it in the original post, but I guess it was easy to miss. We're running different versions of OSX, but I was able to build and run before on this version of OSX. It just broke today.

Comment: For reference I'm running Sierra, they're running El Capitan.