# XCode 9 stop debugging and running application and giving error "The LLDB RPC server has crashed."

Tags: ios, swift, debugging, lldb, xcode9

The LLDB RPC server has crashed. The crash log is located in ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports and has a prefix 'lldb-rpc-server'. Please file a bug and attach the most recent crash log.

Comment: try clean and rebuild it

Comment: I hope you did what they asked i.e. file a bug report with the crash log attached.

Comment: @JeremyP, Yes reported crash log.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is LLDB RPC Server ? When does it crash in Xcode? Why it crashes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43635522/what-is-lldb-rpc-server-when-does-it-crash-in-xcode-why-it-crashes)

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look into [LLDB CRASH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43635522/what-is-lldb-rpc-server-when-does-it-crash-in-xcode-why-it-crashes)

Uninstalling the Xcode and reinstalling it will undo it. Dont know if there is any other known solution as its a known bug of Xcode 8.2 beta and 8.3

Comment: I will try to reinstall Xcode. Hope that will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution for this, this may not be the perfect but kind a fix my problem.

Go to target Build Settings -> Other Swift Flags -> check Debug Values added Remove everything except $(inherited) and -DDEBUG

Remove Derived Data

Clean and Run

https://stackoverflow.com/a/63357101/2699432