# Debugger:The LLDB RPC server has crashed

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, debugging

When it goes to debug point. I am getting below error message.

> **Message from debugger: The LLDB RPC server has crashed. The crash log is located in ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports and has a prefix
>   'lldb-rpc-server'. Please file a bug and attach the most recent crash
>   log.**
>
> xcode version :  9.2 (9C40b)  OS version :10.13.2 (17C88) I have
>   tried below steps,but nothing worked out
>    1. uninstalled and installed the Xcode.
>    2. tried searching for LLDB in debug option.But didn't find out
>    3. Delete all the Simulators and Devices. Reinstalled them

crashLog:

```
Time Awake Since Boot: 21000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        8  RPC packet thread for client tid 00051043 (331843)

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
Stack dump:
0.  error finding type for _T013TrackActivity18HomeViewControllerCD
abort() called

Thread 0:: Connection::RunLoop() packet reading thread  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff578d441a read + 10
1   lldb-rpc-server                 0x000000010f76a1db rpc_common::RPCConnectionSocket::Read(std::__1::basic_string<unsigned char, std::__1::char_traits<unsigned char>, std::__1::allocator<unsigned char> >&, bool) + 173
2   lldb-rpc-server
```

Comment: Well, what does the crash log say?

Comment: Thread 9 Crashed:: RPC packet thread for client tid 0006f4d3 (455891).I could not understand it report.Do you want my entire fle

Comment: LLDB is the LLVM debugger. And yes, you should probably post the important parts of the log as part of your question (the entries that were logged at the time of the incident)

Comment: BoR, I don't know, but post whatever you think might help somebody be able to help you

Comment: Crashed Thread:        8  RPC packet thread for client tid 00051043 (331843)

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Comment: Disabling or removing breakpoints helped: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43635522/what-is-lldb-rpc-server-when-does-it-crash-in-xcode-why-it-crashes