# The request was denied by service delegate (SBMainWorkspace) on iOS 10.0+ simulator & FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain error 1 on iOS 9.3 simulator. Why?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-simulator

When trying to run any of the projects that I usually run I'm getting the following errors for different simulators:

`The request was denied by service delegate (SBMainWorkspace) for reason: unspecified` on iOS 10.0+ simulator

`The operation could not be completed (FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain error 1)` on iOS 9.3 simulator.

This issue began when I tried installing a previous version of Xcode 8.2.1 from what I had been using (8.3). I couldn't build any projects in the 8.2.1, but I could still build in 8.3. I named the 8.2.1 a different name in order to be able to run them side by side. This was something I had done before. However, I needed 8.2.1 for a project and so I deleted **both** and then reinstalled just 8.2.1 according to this post: [How to Completely Uninstall Xcode and Clear All Settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31011062/how-to-completely-uninstall-xcode-and-clear-all-settings).

I've checked the scheme settings in Product > Scheme > Edit scheme > Run > Environment Variables and I've made sure there are no empty environment variables checked. I don't have any environment variables at all now.

I've reset content and settings on the simulators.

I've created a new simulator of a different iOS version. Originally I was just trying on 9.3 and 10.3. I then downloaded the 10.0 and 10.2 and still have the same issue occurring.

I consistently clean my project before running, both (shift + cmd + K) and (shift + alt/option + cmd + K).

I've rebooted my system. I've done everything I can think of. The issue still prevails. What am I missing?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain error 1, "unspecified" is a catch-all error code for something going wrong during launch that wasn't covered by another error code.  There are a couple possible causes for this error code, and it is unfortunate that they do not get displayed in the UI.

I suggest you look in the simulated device's system log to uncover the real cause for the failure.  Run this to see all the logs from CoreSimulatorBridge as that logs the full error when it gets it:

`xcrun simctl spawn booted log show --info --debug --predicate 'processImagePath contains "CoreSimulatorBridge"'`

If that isn't descriptive enough, you might want to also look at the logs for SpringBoard or assertiond, or just use --start and --end to see all the logs for the relevant time range.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I decided to look at all the logs, since just the CoreSimulatorBridge didn't seem as descriptive as I wanted, so I've created a gist for the logs that display when trying to run the app, [here](https://gist.github.com/casperson/fb8c73b9ebea350d0bea0e2de4bf9b3b). I'm running just a bare, test application. I see this line right before the failure, `Unable to get pid for 'UIKitApplication:com.bc.Test1[0xb7b]': No such process (err 3)`. Would that be contributing to the error and how would I fix it, or is there something else you see in the logs that is a cause?

Comment: `Sep  7 10:35:35 l-sff161gtf1-m com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.966F74EA-4C91-481E-9E86-F85C64C8B133.launchd_sim[14543] (UIKitApplication:com.bc.Test1[0xb7b][14816]): Service could not initialize: 11Z705: xpcproxy_sim + 8978 [1475][129F9FAC-19CC-30F2-A45E-9ABBB452A334]: 0x5` is the important line.  it means that posix_spawn failed with EIO.  Unfortunately, I don't have anything more to go on than that, but that doesn't look good.  EIO is frequently an omen of hardware failure.  I'd take a look through your host logs for any other such problems and backup your data.