# Removed PrivateFrameworks from /Library/Developer/ Xcode crashing on launch

Tags: ios, xcode

Is there a way to download this /PrivateFrameworks folder back? It seems like this has the framework to make simulator work. I have re-downloaded xcode9 and it does not come back. Also tried re-installing xcode command line tools but this PrivateFrameworks doesnt seem to be part of the Xcode bundle nor the Command Line Tools bundle. Idea's Anyone?

Comment: You got no backup? If not think about using one in the future

Answer (score 16):

There's no need to get a copy from a friend. The contents of PrivateFrameworks come inside an installer package provided with Xcode starting from version 9. You should have this file as part of your Xcode install, even if you just downloaded Xcode from the App Store.

Just run in your Terminal:

```
open /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Resources/Packages/XcodeSystemResources.pkg
```

And your PrivateFrameworks folder will magically be back.

Comment: This also fixed my "Error loading required libraries. If there is an ongoing installation please wait for it to complete. Otherwise reinstall." issue when I restored my macOS from backup, thanks!