# Xcode Dsymutil error - dsymutil failed with exit code 4 - need to generate dSym

Tags: ios, xcode, compilation, dsym

I am trying to compile my xcode iOS app that has dependencies to OneSignal, GoogleMaps, and Dlib libraries.

However, I am unable to compile my app

The following is my environment:

```
XCode 9.2 (9C40b)
MacOS High Sierra (10.13.1)
```

The following is my current XCode configurations. Nothing special (I think).

```
Build Configuration - Release
```

The following is the error generated from compiling the app in xcode:

> GenerateDSYMFile
>   /Users/some/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PortalCom-euiqqovslgrjiladmbryjcsdkwoa/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/PortalCom/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/PortalCom.app.dSYM
>   /Users/some/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PortalCom-euiqqovslgrjiladmbryjcsdkwoa/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/PortalCom/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/PortalCom.app/PortalCom
>           cd /Users/some/Documents/project/railerdotcom/railer_ios/PortalCom
>           export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>           /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/dsymutil
>   /Users/some/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PortalCom-euiqqovslgrjiladmbryjcsdkwoa/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/PortalCom/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/PortalCom.app/PortalCom
>   -o /Users/some/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PortalCom-euiqqovslgrjiladmbryjcsdkwoa/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/PortalCom/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/PortalCom.app.dSYM
>
> ```
> Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/dsymutil
> ```
>
> failed with exit code 4

There is also a llvm-dsymutil crash that is sent to apple when the compilation error happened. https://gist.github.com/axilaris/4c5f4351d3c2287c1e45fde159bb66b8

**UPDATE:**
my app can compile with 8.3.3 (8E3004b). This is confirmed with 2 different computers.

How to solve this issue with latest XCode 9.2 ? If I change the "DEBUG INFORMATION FORMAT" to "DWARF" instead of "DWARF with dSYM File", then it works but it means I dont have dSym files. I need to compile that generated dSYM for crashlytics.

Comment: Have you cleared DerivedData data? Path:- /Users/Your-User/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

Comment: is there any script file in your run script in build Phase ?

Comment: thanks for replying, @navroz, i'ved cleaned all. based on this SO, i'ved used the one line rm to completely clean xcode but result is the same. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31011062/how-to-completely-uninstall-xcode-and-clear-all-settings

Comment: there is no scripts. the only odd setting is that it needs to be compiled with build configuration "release"