# Flutter - Failed to build iOS app on Android Studio

Tags: ios, android-studio, flutter

I'm using Flutter with Android-Studio, everything was working great (i.e. compiling and deploying to iOS simulators except until I installed [Fastlane Tools](https://fastlane.tools). The building process now is broken somehow! I'm not sure if it's from Fastlane or something else though, but now I'm stuck and cannot deploy to iOS anymore.

Steps taken/tried already:

1. Removing XCode & CommandLineTools (using this post: [Complete removal old XCode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33812614/2198253))
2. Reinstalling XCode 9.2 (from AppStore)
3. Reinstalling CommandLineTools for XCode 9.2 (dl from developer tools page)
4. Reinstalling/updating ios-deply using:

   npm install -g ios-deploy --unsafe-perm=true

Error log is on PasteBin to reduce post size:

```
https://pastebin.com/HQdJYLBr
```

Flutter doctor report:

```
[✓] Flutter (on Mac OS X 10.13.3 17D102, locale en-AE, channel alpha)
    • Flutter version 0.0.22-pre.1 at /Users/user999/github/flutter
    • Framework revision 553fc4264e (3 weeks ago), 2018-03-01 09:30:25 -0800
    • Engine revision 6921873c71
    • Tools Dart version 2.0.0-dev.16.0
    • Engine Dart version 2.0.0-edge.da1f52592ef73fe3afa485385cb995b9aec0181a

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 27.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/user999/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-27, build-tools 27.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-915-b08)

[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 9.2)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 9.2, Build version 9C40b
    • ios-deploy 1.9.2
    • CocoaPods version 1.4.0

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.0)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-915-b08)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2017.3.4)
    • Flutter plugin version 21.2.3
    • Dart plugin version 173.4548.30

[✓] Connected devices
    • iPhone X • 2AD97E20-6FB5-4086-BDC0-EBE6138FBD79 • ios • iOS 11.2 (simulator)
```

Any suggestions, please?

Comment: To solve my own issue, I started the project all over again, copying required files from old project to the new one. Couldn't solve it otherwise!

Answer (score 2):

This answer is for the ones who are still trying to work with Xcode 9.2. Starting April, 2020, all apps submitted to the App Store will need to be built with Xcode 11. So don't try to build your Flutter IOS App with XCode 9.2.
Flutter is also changing rapidly therefore, it is better to use the latest XCode version to avoid any deprecated API issue.

For reference visit:
  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/4125