# Storyboard UICollectionViewCell shows up, then goes blank

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, interface-builder, xcode9

### Problem:

I am working on a `UIViewController` on my Storyboard/Interface Builder, with a `UICollectionView` in it that defines a `UICollectionViewCell`. Everytime I change something in this cell, all its subviews goes to blank white, making it impossible to see anything. Also when I update constraints frame won't move even if I refresh, like the whole interface builder is broken. It's only for this `UIViewController`, sometimes does it for an other one. Interface Builder Builds show warnings from Pods (I can't help it). I have no broken constraints.

### (Very) Temporary solution:

If I quit Xcode, clean, rebuild and re-open the Storyboard, it will be back to "almost" normal (meaning not all views shows properly but at least I can see them and it's not fully white) until I switch to an other file and come back. When I come back to the storyboard will be blank again. Sometimes I have to delete my DerivedData and the cell will display perfect. Only for a few minutes.

Also, I do not have any constraints warnings or anything.

**EDIT**: I removed all classes from all the views in the cell, just in case something in my custom views was causing these problems. My views mostly implement layers and gradients so I thought I might have been doing something wrong breaking the IB rendering. On the top of the cell there is a custom `UIView` that I made, that uses a `CAGradientLayer`. If I remove the class from this view, the cell will start displaying again. But I can't be sure this is the cause since when I leave the storyboard and come back on it, the cell will be white again. Without having putting back the class in place.

**EDIT2**: I uninstalled and reinstalled Xcode and cocoapods. Updated the pods. Created a new xcworspace.

### Screenshot

[image]

[image]

### Details on my environment

I am using Swift, XCode 9.3, Cocoapods 1.5.0, High Sierre 10.13.4
Feel free to ask any other details
My Pods (that generate lots of warnings due to swift 4 compatibility) :

```
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
  pod 'FSPagerView'
  pod 'CropViewController'
  pod 'SwiftLint'
  pod 'Parse'
  pod 'Parse/FacebookUtils'
  pod 'ImagePicker'
  pod 'XLPagerTabStrip', '~> 8.0'
  pod 'Eureka'
```

Comment: may be you can re order the views from back to front

Comment: Yeah, I tried everything already. It doesnt change anything.
Unless I delete DerivedData and It works !

Comment: Are you using a @IBDesignable class?

Comment: I am using the FSPagerView framework, seems to cause rendering problems... Otherwise no

Comment: are you working with two Xcode version? Sometimes Xcode misbehavious, when we open two versions.

Comment: I only have one version. I uninstalled and reinstalled Xcode

Comment: Is "Automatically Refresh Views" are check in menu Editor category of top menu of Xcode?

Comment: I am, but I removed all the classes to check and it still does the bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problem was caused by Cocoapods an Xcode.**

First, I realized by cloning my project on an other machine, that my Xcode was not displaying the Interface Builder errors, but only the warnings.

**How to display Interface Builder errors ?**

On the left pane in Xcode (the one with the file hierarchy), click on the last item looking like a comic bubble. You will see the build, workspace and interface builder errors. My Xcode for some reason would not display anything, so I re-installed for the second time Xcode.

**How to properly re-install Xcode ?**

Simply delete all those files :

```
/Applications/Xcode.app
/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist
~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode
~/Library/Application Support/Xcode
~/Library/Developer
~/Library/Developer/Xcode
~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator
```

Source : [How to Completely Uninstall Xcode and Clear All Settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31011062/how-to-completely-uninstall-xcode-and-clear-all-settings)

**Then, Xcode showed me this error :**

[image]

Finally, I could confirm that removing the `pod` related to this framework would stop breaking my storyboard.
By looking more on the internet, I found that this is an actual issue related to Frameworks signing, caused by cocoa pods.

I uninstalled `Cocoapods` `1.5.0` and re-installed the `1.4.0` version.

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
sudo gem install cocoapods -v 1.4.0
```

Source : [Xcode - @IBDesignables - Required code signing missing for X.framework](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrbKa.png)

All problems fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You should call the super parent in the **awakeFromNib** method.

> You must call the super implementation of awakeFromNib to give parent classes the opportunity to perform any additional initialization they require.

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
  super.awakeFromNib()
  setup()
}
```

Comment: `prepareForInterfaceBuilder` also needs to call super

Answer (score 1):

Can be one of your Dependency, look at the **issues** on these **dependencies**.

Try to remove your dependencies one by one.