# Xcode 9.4 not showing unit tests

Tags: swift, xcode, unit-testing, xctest

I've a project that uses Swift 4.1, Cocoapods and has some unit tests. These tests were visible on Xcode 9.3, after I updated it to Xcode 9.4 the test navigator gets stuck and even deleting the derived folder, cleaning the project, reinstalling the software and restarting the Mac **does not** solve this issue. Must be a misconfiguration on the project (but I didn't change anything).
Any idea what I can do?

[image: Xcode stuck]

(Image has been resized)

Comment: What I did in a similar situation is open the test files direct form the Finder, copy out their contents, and then in Xcode delete the test target completely and start over.

Comment: @matt Issue solved, simply do a deep delete of Xcode and install back.

Comment: Right, well, you said "reinstalling the software" so I assumed you'd done that already.

Comment: @matt Only the `Xcode.app` file I meant. Not the cache (which is located in different places).

Answer (score 2):

Managed to solve the issue:

Simply uninstall all entries of Xcode following this answer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33812614/2430555) and install Xcode 9.4 again.

Comment: I suspect this might be useful to others. :)

Comment: I agree, the issue was very complex but simple to solve.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue with Xcode 10.2.1 and solved it by making sure all my code was checked in and pushed, then creating a new sandbox (I'm using git).

That was easier than trying to figure out what Xcode files were causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have disabled xcode indexing. if you have delete it using the terminal command

```
defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode IDEIndexDisable
```

Then restart your xcode. It worked for me.