# xcode is not opening after downgrade from V9 to V8

Tags: xcode

I'm trying to downgrade from xcode 9 to xcode 8, I have deleted the 9 version already then i realize that version 8 is not opening working.

all what happening that when i click on xcode icon it will show the very first new project screen for less than 1 second and disappear again.

macOS High Sierra 
Version 10.13.6

Comment: What's your MacOS?

Comment: macOS High Sierra 
Version 10.13.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have Xcode pops up a window with a list of most recent projects, but then switch off very fast. that mean you have every thing fine and all you need is to go to any txt file in your computer (file.txt) right click open with and select you Xcode you have installed it Will work fine

Answer (score 1):

At start you need to completely uninstall XCode 9, including derived data, devtools, simulators, etc. Type 'uninstall xcode completely' in Google and you will find many advises of how to do that, including at StackOverflow, e.g.

[How to Completely Uninstall Xcode and Clear All Settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31011062/how-to-completely-uninstall-xcode-and-clear-all-settings)

After that you can install XCode 8 by placing XCode.app to Applications folder. Everything else it should do during first run.