# Xcode archive error after renaming user folder

Tags: xcode, macos

I renamed my Mac's user folder (`Users/somename`).
After doing so, when trying to submit (archive) an app, I get:

[image: error]

I tried:

- Deleting Xcode, as well as *many* related files (https://stackoverflow.com/a/33812614/5306470), then reinstalling it.
- Running: `defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode`
- Running: `sudo xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch`

But the error persists.

**How can update the path in which Xcode looks for this information?**

> Notes:
>
> - "dani" is the **old** name.
> - I am the only user of the Mac.
> - I never got this error before, and I have published several apps successfully.
> - Running: Xcode 10.1 (10B61)
> - Running: macOS Mojave 10.14.2 (18C54)

Comment: Did you try adding another user, logging into it and use xcode via it ? Hope it doesn't refer to old installation. Moreover, I think that xcode relevant caches weren't clear your side

Comment: Haha I agree with you. Just shared an idea :) Did you try with xcode 9 ?

Comment: Hmm. May be you can search for all xcode relevant folders and files in Library or other places. Good luck!

Comment: **Note:** I gave up after hours with tech support and reverted the folder's name. That fixed it (if we can call it a fix), so I won't be trying eventual suggestions but we'll leave this up cuz docs.

Comment: Glad you were able to resume your work

Answer (score 0):

I know its late but I encountered the same issue after taking over a work Mac from a coworker and changing the user folder. My solution to the problem was to create the requested directory and put the required file there. This solved the problem for me and the file in the desired directory was actually updated during the process so I believe the problem corrected itself.

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: Xcode is looking for a file that doesn't exist (in the place it is looking), if you copy the file from where it is now to where xcode is looking it will proceed as normal.

This means you recreate the old user folder and only put the /Library/Caches/com.apple.amp.itmstransporter folder with its contents there.