# Xcode 10.1 Swift file modification triggers multitude of compiler errors

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode10

While editing a Swift file, I am getting several:

```
@objc attribute used without importing module 'Foundation'
@objc can only be used with members of classes, @objc protocols, and concrete
extensions of classes 
Use of unresolved identifier 
Use of undeclared type
```

compiler errors.

For instance,

```
@objc func returnTrue() -> Bool { return true }
```

complains `@objc attribute used without importing module 'Foundation'` even though my `pch` file contains `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>`

I have restarted Xcode/Mac; [uninstalled/reinstalled Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33812614/1803879); deleted derived data; changed/reverted the pch file; checked class target memberships; and cleaned the build folder (several times). I can successfully compile and run the code.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Could you share some code that is giving those errors?

Comment: `@objc func returnTrue() -> Bool { return true }` 
@LorenzOliveto the compiler is pretty much complaining about everything.

Comment: Why are you using an outdated version of Xcode? 10.2.1 is the latest version. Also, have you tried restarting Xcode?

Comment: @Dávid Pásztor codebase will not compile with latest version (believe it was a swift migration issue); I have restarted Xcode (and my mac). Thanks

Comment: Post the whole relevant code, with a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: pch file is not available/used in Swift, have you tried adding 'import Foundation' in your Swift class?

Answer (score 0):

As a programmer, I am not a fan of *magic* answers, but the following worked for me (assuming my branch is `MyBranch`):

1. Committed and pushed my local `MyBranch`'s working copy changes.
2. Switched branches. Built. Deleted my local `MyBranch`.
3. Checked out the remote `MyBranch`.

*Voila!*