# How to uninstall react-native-cli on mac?

Tags: react-native, npm

How can I uninstall react-native-cli on Mac??

I tried `npm uninstall react-native-cli` and it gives me below.

```
npm WARN eslint-plugin-react@7.12.4 requires a peer of eslint@^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-plugin-react-native@3.6.0 requires a peer of eslint@^3.17.0 || ^4 || ^5 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

I want to completely wipe-off my react native environment and re-install it. What should I do?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Uninstalling global packages

To uninstall an unscoped global package, on the command line, use the `uninstall` command with the `-g` flag. Include the scope if the package is scoped.

```
npm uninstall -g react-native-cli
```

After close commad line and Do turn on commad line

```bash
❯ which react-native
# react-native not found
```

Comment: Hello Thanks for helping me out consistently. I'm facing one weird issue that completely broke down my environment while following your AsyncStorage answer... could you please help me out?

Comment: I can't check enough time passes. okay. I will

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57248850/unable-to-resolve-module-react-native-community-async-storage-broke-down-my-r

Comment: I just posted the new question @hong develop

Comment: I did that and I still can do "react-native init GarbageProject"

Comment: @AndriiKapinos Try turning the terminal off and on after running, and if it still works, use the `which react-native` command in the terminal to see where the installation is again.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to completely remove react native environment you need to remove CLI

```
npm uninstall -g react-native-cli @react-native-community/cli
```

next, remove watchman

```
brew uninstall watchman
```

remove Android env:

[How to completely uninstall Android Studio on Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625622/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio-on-mac)

remove IOS env:

[How to Completely Uninstall Xcode and Clear All Settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31011062/how-to-completely-uninstall-xcode-and-clear-all-settings)