# `unable to resolve module @react-native-community/async-storage` broke down my React Native environment

Tags: react-native

[image]

I'm basically having the issue same as here.

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1899

### How I got this error

Since `AsyncStorage` is deprecated, I tried to install `@react-native-community/async-storage` following the [official documentation](https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage)

But it failed completely as I got the error above.
Thus I wanted to roll back to my previous working version except none of what I did worked.

#### None of these solved my problem

1. 4 commands suggested on the error screen
2. undoing `yarn add` with `yarn remove`
3. I also did `npm install @react-native-community/async-storage`, did not work.
   3.5 so I did `npm uninstall @react-native-community/async-storage` It was removed, but roll-back did not work.
4. Re-installing the `react-native-cli`
5. Re-creating a completely [new project from scratch](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started), but it is still giving the same error.

I could not find a solution for this. Please help.

Comment: TL;DR: I reboot my machine and it fixed. Weird.

Answer (score 9):

If it's on `iOS` you probably forgot to do `pod install`.

Paste this inside `ios/Podfile`:

```
  pod 'RNCAsyncStorage', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-community/async-storage'
```

then just do `cd ios && pod install`

EDIT.

I createad a project from scratch, this are the steps i did to make asyncStorage run on iOS and Android:

1) `react-native init AsyncTest`

2) `npm i @react-native-community/async-storage`

(trying to use asyncStorage during this step shows error, but works on Android)

3) Pasted inside Podfile this pod:

```
  pod 'RNCAsyncStorage', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-community/async-storage'
```

4) From terminal, assuming you are in the project folder do `cd ios` and `pod install`

5) Project run succesfully on iOS and works.

react-native version was 0.60.4

This is how the project test App.js was for the test:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import AsyncStorageTest from './AsyncStorageTest'
const App = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <AsyncStorageTest />
    </View>
  );
};

export default App
```

And AsyncStorageTest is:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native'
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

export class AsyncStorageTest extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            storedData: "myValue"
        }
    }


storeData = async () => {
    console.log("inside storeData")
    try {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('Test', 'TestValue')
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
}

getData = async () => {
    console.log("inside getData")
    try {
        const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('Test')
        this.setState({ storedData: value })

    } catch (e) {
        // error reading value
    }
}

render() {
    return (
        <View style={{ marginTop: 40 }}>
            <Text> {this.state.storedData}</Text>
            <Button title={"storeData"} onPress={this.storeData}></Button>
            <Button title={"getData"} onPress={this.getData}></Button>
        </View>
    )
}
}


export default AsyncStorageTest
```

Tested and worked, see if you missed something.

Make sure the that `@react-native-community/async-storage` is unlinked from your project.

Comment: Let me try this. But why would it still not work after I remove it?

Comment: I didn't notice that you tried to uninstall it. Maybe you forgot to update your code afterwards? I'm using react-native 0.60 and this is the solution i had to adopt to make it work. I don't know if you edited your comment for a reason, but this is for react-native versions >0.60 as iOS uses cocoapods to run now

Comment: There is no way I forgot to update my code because I re-created the new project from scratch. So I am supposed to end up with the initial code provided by the react native.

Comment: I re-booted my computer and it works now... It gave me `no bundle url` error, i ran npm install and it works now. i have no idea why

Comment: Pretty strange yes, glad you found a solution!

Comment: @Leonard. Got the same issue. Tried all things you've mentioned above but nothing works. Of course tried to restart my windows pc and even tried to run it on Linux. Kinda weird as it is working before with no errors and I haven't change any in the code!!. Please anyone have an idea what's the problem?

Comment: @ilovejavaAJ using sublime text’s find in folder, try searching for the phrase  “async-storage” in every single file inside your react project. Did you remove everything from npm, apt-get as well?

Comment: @ilovejavaAJ if nothing works, try re-installing everything including node as well! Or check your /usr/local/bin or any environment variable path

Comment: I edited my question, see if you missed some steps @ilovejavaAJ

Comment: I have the same issue but I am on android and the dependency is in a linked  module as a peer dependencies, I use [this configuration](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/issues/1238) , any clue ?

Answer (score 7):

Somehow the path to the package got changed.

This helped me:

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
```

Answer (score 6):

For someone like me please double-check this as well:

When you install `npm i @react-native-community/async-storage` you should import it as `import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';` and DO NOT import is as `import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';`

Comment: @Hylle you're not alone :D

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue following the import...

**import {AsyncStorage} from 'react-native';**

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by installing `@react-native-community/async-storage` aliased to `@react-native-async-storage/async-storage`

The command was

`yarn add @react-native-async-storage/async-storage@npm:@react-native-community/async-storage`

or

`npm install --save @react-native-async-storage/async-storage@npm:@react-native-community/async-storage`

Answer (score 1):

When you install npm install @react-native-community/async-storage

You could import => import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
Dont import this => import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

Answer (score 0):

after i run npm install react-native-dotenv
i take this error,

then i rerun npm install;
cd ios;pod install;cd ..;

and then close the terminal and uninstall app from phone,and restart them,it's works.

my version "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.5",