# What is the equivalent of UserDefaults in React Native for both iOS and Android

Tags: reactjs, react-native, nsuserdefaults

I want to save user information like id, email, etc when login is successful in my react native app. Now coming from the iOS background one way was to use UserDefaults to store information that keeps the information even if the app is killed and opened again.

Upon searching I found that one way is to use `AsyncStoage` but I'm getting a warning nowadays that it's going to be how would I. achieve something like NSUserDefaults in React Native?

[image]

Comment: yes, you can use use async storage for this. Also the warning is telling you exactly what you need to do to get rid of the warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`npm i @react-native-community/async-storage`

and follow [installation](https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/install/) on iOS and Android

and change your import to :

`import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';`

write string value :

```
const storeData = async (value) => {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('@storage_Key', value)
  } catch (e) {
    // saving error
  }
}
```

read string value :

```
const getData = async () => {
  try {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@storage_Key')
    if(value !== null) {
      // value previously stored
    }
  } catch(e) {
    // error reading value
  }
}
```

Comment: There is an error when I implement this `[Error: undefined Unable to resolve module @react-native-async-storage/async-storage from src/components/CreateAccount.js: @react-native-async-storage/async-storage could not be found within the project.`

Comment: please see here if you are using on iOS: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57248950/4557781