# How to fix dsymutil in Xamarin

Tags: xcode, xamarin, xamarin.ios, dsymutil

I am trying to build the iOS App on a real device but unfortunately I get hit by a

```
dsymutil exited with code 1
```

Things I did:

- I did search google but it says my Harddisk is full which is not the
  case.
- I did try to clean and build multiple times - No success
- I did try to reinstall CommandTools by using command `xcode-select
  --install` - No Success
- I did remove the CommandTools and then did the reinstall - No Success

Just an FYI

- I am using Xcode 11.4 Beta 2
- I am logged in with my Apple Account on the Xcode

What my cause this issue?

Any other info you would like to ask do ask.

Thanks

Build Log:

```
  CIS.iOS -> D:\VS Projects\CIS\CIS\CIS\CIS.iOS\bin\iPhone\Debug\CIS.iOS.exe

  Detected signing identity:

    Code Signing Key: "#####"
 (7ECA06BC28377204C91D2E63E69C233982161B28)

    Provisioning Profile: "Development" (5aa7573d-6dc8-43e4-9bb0-c65efc5a361a)

    Bundle Id: com.#####

    App Id: 37M96SGRTW.com.#####

  /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/bin/mtouch @/Users/zilon/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/CIS.iOS/0e17d2ede92713351eb68ac0146dd15c/obj/iPhone/Debug/response-file.rsp --gcc_flags=-ObjC 

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(842,3): warning MT4174: Unable to locate the block to delegate conversion method for the method CIS.iOS.AppDelegate.WillPresentNotification's parameter #3.

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/dsymutil -t 4 -z -o bin/iPhone/Debug/CIS.iOS.app/../Protobuf.framework.dSYM bin/iPhone/Debug/CIS.iOS.app/Frameworks/Protobuf.framework/Protobuf 

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(963,3): error MSB6006: "dsymutil" exited with code 1.
```

Comment: There will probably be a bit more to such errors, can you show us the part of the build log where it fails?

Comment: Hi , does it works before ? And better not using beta version of xcode to test xamarin , there will be conflict in somewhere we not knowing .

Comment: I am using the beta version because the current release is 11.3.1 (Stable) but it doesn't support my iOS device which is 13.4 only the 11.4.2 beta supports it

Comment: @Cheesebaron I have added Build Logs do check

Comment: @NoobCoder Does it works in previous version , not suggesting testing with beta version . By the way , the error shows that `Unable to locate the block to delegate conversion method for the method CIS.iOS.AppDelegate.WillPresentNotification's parameter #3` methoth `WillPresentNotification` occur error , you can have a check that .

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT nope. I did a hard reset now and its gone now. Reinstalled the whole OS and then reinstalled the Xcode and other tools its now working. But still no official solution found

Comment: @NoobCoder Okey , whether the reinstalled OS is stable version ,right ?

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT yes I reused the same dmg to reinstall the OS and Updated it like before. Kinda was pulling my hairs when this error came out. But now its gone so I am kinda relaxed

Comment: @NoobCoder Got it , glad solved it . You can share this solution as an answer , other people will know it .

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT I wouldn't call this a solution as I had to Uninstall everything

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT I wouldn't call this a solution as I had to Uninstall everything

Comment: @NoobCoder Okey , I guess the problem should be the Beta version of Xcode as I said before .

Comment: Find the answer in the below link, it works perfectly. https://stackoverflow.com/a/71759982/5043390

Answer (score 6):

Here is the solution:

> I went inside Xcode.
>
> Preferences>Locations> Command Line Tools. Mine was on 13.2, needed to
> upgrade to 13.3 (Thought I already had but it must not have done it
> automatically)

[Click here for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71759982/5043390)

Comment: Thanks for this. When I went to Preferences>Locations> Command Line Tools in Xcode I got nothing.... the field was blank. I've added the right version and the error has been fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Check for Xamarin.ios version, mine was incompatible with visual studio Mac

i changed it when I was debuging on a windows machine connected to a Mac and VS windows said if I wanted to download compatible version, clicked yes and it downloaded and installed on the Mac computer

After that, I wasn't unable to debug on physical devices

suddenly after almost giving up a "Xamarin.ios update is ready, click to install update" came on VS Mac

after that I got no errors

Answer (score 1):

This discussion was very helpful. I also had to make sure my VS for Mac updates were all installed. Once they were, everything needed to align just right, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

> We have resolved this issue now. All we did is we just updated Xamarin.iOS, Mono Framework MDK and Visual Studio for Mac to the latest versions.
>
> Just go to Visual Studio → Check for Updates and then update all.

Source: [xamarin_forums](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/181016/error-dsymutil-exited-with-code-1)

Answer (score 0):

The error is kind of a hair puller.

So here is how I did it

First I uninstalled ALL of the XCODE

I followed this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31011062/how-to-completely-uninstall-xcode-and-clear-all-settings) on stackoverflow

After that I downloaded the Xcode from Apple from this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335747/how-to-download-xcode-dmg-or-xip-file)

Also download the CommandLine tools for that version. After that it worked and now I am not getting any error.

Remember this that CommandLine Tool versions should also match. 11.4.2 will not work with 11.3.1. I tested this and wasted alot of time.