# Xamarin - Error: dsymutil exited with code 72

Tags: ios, xcode, visual-studio, xamarin

Recently upgraded to VS for Mac 8.10.21, when building apps, I'm getting:

```
/Xamarin.Shared.targets(3,3): Error: dsymutil exited with code 72
```

This is with Xcode 13.3.

Full version details below:

```
Visual Studio Community 2019 for Mac
Version 8.10.21 (build 4)
Installation UUID: b7d9f3e8-a2eb-4a6a-a2fa-6a53e9637a56
    GTK+ 2.24.23 (Raleigh theme)
    Xamarin.Mac 6.18.0.23 (d16-6 / 088c73638)

    Package version: 612000162

Mono Framework MDK
Runtime:
    Mono 6.12.0.162 (2020-02/2ca650f1f62) (64-bit)
    Package version: 612000162

Roslyn (Language Service)
3.10.0-4.21269.26+029847714208ebe49668667c60ea5b0a294e0fcb

NuGet
Version: 5.9.0.7134

.NET SDK (x64)
SDK: Not installed
MSBuild SDKs: /Applications/Visual Studio.app/Contents/Resources/lib/monodevelop/bin/MSBuild/Current/bin/Sdks

.NET Core Runtime
Runtime: Not installed

Xamarin.Profiler
Version: 1.6.15.68
Location: /Applications/Xamarin Profiler.app/Contents/MacOS/Xamarin Profiler

Updater
Version: 11

Apple Developer Tools
Xcode 13.3 (20102)
Build 13E113

Xamarin.Mac
Xamarin.Mac not installed. Can't find /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/Current/Version.

Xamarin.iOS
Version: 15.8.0.0 (Visual Studio Community)
Hash: f10d9e023
Branch: xcode13.3
Build date: 2022-03-15 11:47:35-0400

Xamarin Designer
Version: 16.11.0.60
Hash: 56f9b80b0
Branch: remotes/origin/d16-11
Build date: 2021-12-15 01:44:16 UTC

Xamarin.Android
Version: 12.0.0.3 (Visual Studio Community)
Commit: xamarin-android/d16-11/f0e3c2d
Android SDK: /Users/jon/Library/Android/sdk
    Supported Android versions:
        4.4 (API level 19)
        5.0 (API level 21)
        6.0 (API level 23)
        7.0 (API level 24)
        7.1 (API level 25)
        8.0 (API level 26)
        8.1 (API level 27)

SDK Tools Version: 26.1.1
SDK Platform Tools Version: 32.0.0
SDK Build Tools Version: 31.0.0

Build Information: 
Mono: c633fe9
Java.Interop: xamarin/java.interop/d16-11@476bb5b
ProGuard: Guardsquare/proguard/v7.0.1@912d149
SQLite: xamarin/sqlite/3.35.4@85460d3
Xamarin.Android Tools: xamarin/xamarin-android-tools/d16-11@87af37b

Eclipse Temurin JDK
Java SDK: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-8.jdk/Contents/Home
1.8.0.302
Android Designer EPL code available here:
https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidDesigner.EPL

Android SDK Manager
Version: 16.10.0.13
Hash: 1b81df5
Branch: remotes/origin/d16-10
Build date: 2021-11-12 00:17:32 UTC

Android Device Manager
Version: 16.10.0.15
Hash: 89dcc0b
Branch: remotes/origin/d16-10
Build date: 2021-11-12 00:17:52 UTC

Build Information
Release ID: 810210004
Git revision: eb0b2f7259d35b7d767c79d91d356881227e0985
Build date: 2022-03-17 17:18:28-04
Build branch: release-8.10

Operating System
Mac OS X 12.1.0
Darwin 21.2.0 Darwin Kernel Version 21.2.0
    Sun Nov 28 20:29:10 PST 2021
    root:xnu-8019.61.5~1/RELEASE_ARM64_T8101 x86_64
```

Any ideas? Can't find any reference to "code 72" anywhere else.

Comment: You can report the problem(visual studio related) on Microsoft developer community for better support : https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=41&entry=problem.

Answer (score 8):

I had this exact error.

I went inside Xcode.

Preferences>Locations> Command Line Tools. Mine was on 13.2, needed to upgrade to 13.3 (Thought I already had but it must not have done it automatically)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks bro!! I actually had to downgrade my xcode version from 13.3.1 to 13.3 and it fixed my issue! I was getting this error when trying to run my ios app on a physical device in release mode. /Xamarin.Shared.targets(3,3): Error: dsymutil exited with code 72

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the screen shot. In my case, Xcode 13.4 had switched command line tools to Xcode 14 (Beta).