# Slow Xcode when switching files

Tags: xcode, macos

This is an issue I have had for years now. It wasn't a problem since I only used Xcode time to time but now that I'm starting developing for iOS, it is more important.

When working on a project, no matter the language I'm using, switching between files takes a minimum of 2 seconds. The problem doesn't occur when switching between tabs.

I had this issue on my old MacBook Pro 13" 2011 and it followed me on my new 16" (TimeMachine imported). My friend who is still working on a 2011 13" doesn't have the same issue and I can't find any one on internet who has it.

I have already uninstalled Xcode and deleted all "background files" (following these instructions: [How to Completely Uninstall Xcode and Clear All Settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31011062/how-to-completely-uninstall-xcode-and-clear-all-settings)), no developper account registered, no custom theme in Xcode and the macOS console only show three small errors, here are they just in case:

```
Xcode   NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1100
usernoted   Legacy client com.apple.dt.Xcode connecting to modern client. You can't mix modern clients with legacy clients. <ClientConnect: 0x00007fc0cb61d140 identifier: com.apple.dt.Xcode pid: 50787 type: Application>
usernoted   Push Client com.apple.dt.Xcode registered push with environment production with types 4, cloudkit: 0
tccd    {ID: com.apple.dt.Xcode, PID[50787], auid: 503, euid: 503, binary path: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode'} attempted to call TCCAccessRequest without the com.apple.private.tcc.manager.check-by-audit-token entitlement
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that has the same problem, I fixed it by uninstalling XCode using AppCleaner and then re-installing. The app probably removed files that I couldn't find.